# Scraping information from library catalog

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am working on a project to scrape catalog information for books from a specific library. The script I have so far can scrape all the cells from the table. However, I'm confused as to how to return only the specific cells of the New Britain library.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

mypage = 'http://lci-mt.iii.com/iii/encore/record/C__Rb1872125__S%28*%29%20f%3Aa%20c%3A47__P0%2C3__Orightresult__U__X6?lang=eng&suite=cobalt'
response = requests.get(mypage)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

data = []
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'itemTable'})


rows = table.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele]) # Get rid of empty values

for index, libraryinfo in enumerate(data):
    print(index, libraryinfo)
```

Here's an example output for the New Britain library from the script:

```
["New Britain, Main Library - Children's Department", 'J FIC PALACIO', 'Check Shelf']
```

Rather than returning all the cells, how would I only return the cells concerning the New Britain library? I only want the library name and the checkout status as well.

The desired output would be:

```
["New Britain, Main Library - Children's Department", 'Check Shelf']
```

There can be more than one cell, because a book can have multiple copies at the same library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to simply filter out data based on a specific field (the first one in your example) you could build a comprehension:

```
[element for element in data if 'New Britain' in element[0]]
```

The example you provided eliminate empty values which makes the data elements have different sizes. This makes it harder to know which field correspond to each data component. Using dicts we can make the data more understandable and easier to treat.

Some of the fields seemed to have empty chunks inside of it (with only space-like characters [`'\n'`, `'\r'`, `'\t'`, `' '`]). So strip would not remove those. Combining it with a simple regex can help improve that. I wrote a simple function to do that:

```
def squish(s):
    return re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', s)
```

Summing up, I believe this will help you:

```
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def squish(s):
    return re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', s)


def filter_by_location(data, location_name):
    return [x for x in data if location_name.lower() in x['Location'].lower()]


mypage = 'http://lci-mt.iii.com/iii/encore/record/C__Rb1872125__S%28*%29%20f%3Aa%20c%3A47__P0%2C3__Orightresult__U__X6?lang=eng&suite=cobalt'
response = requests.get(mypage)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

data = []
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'itemTable'})

headers = [squish(element.text.strip()) for element in table.find('tr').find_all('th')]

for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    cols = [squish(element.text.strip()) for element in row.find_all('td')]
    data.append({k:v for k, v in zip(headers, cols)})

filtered_data = filter_by_location(data, 'New Britain')
for x in filtered_data:
    print('Location: {}'.format(x['Location']))
    print('Status: {}'.format(x['Status']))
    print()
```

Running it I got the following result:

```
Location: New Britain, Jefferson Branch - Children's Department
Status: Check Shelf

Location: New Britain, Main Library - Children's Department
Status: Check Shelf

Location: New Britain, Main Library - Children's Department
Status: Check Shelf
```

Answer (score 0):

Filtering out rows that does not concern New Britain only requires you to check if the first element of `cols` (i.e. `cols[0]`) has the name of the library.

Obtaining only the library names and the checkout status is simple. You just need to access the first and third elements of `cols` (i.e. `[cols[0], cols[2]]`) since they have the library name and checkout status, respectively.

You can try replacing `data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])` with the following.

```
# We gotta do this to skip empty rows.
if len(cols) == 0:
    continue

if 'New Britain' in cols[0]:
    data.append([cols[0], cols[2]])
```

Your code will look like the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

mypage = 'http://lci-mt.iii.com/iii/encore/record/C__Rb1872125__S%28*%29%20f%3Aa%20c%3A47__P0%2C3__Orightresult__U__X6?lang=eng&suite=cobalt'
response = requests.get(mypage)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

data = []
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'itemTable'})

rows = table.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]

    if len(cols) == 0:
        continue

    if 'New Britain' in cols[0]:
        data.append([cols[0], cols[2]])

for index, libraryinfo in enumerate(data):
    print(index, libraryinfo)
```

Output:

```
0 ["New Britain, Jefferson Branch - Children's Department", 'Check Shelf']
1 ["New Britain, Main Library - Children's Department", 'Check Shelf']
2 ["New Britain, Main Library - Children's Department", 'Check Shelf']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the desired content:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "http://lci-mt.iii.com/iii/encore/record/C__Rb1872125__S%28*%29%20f%3Aa%20c%3A47__P0%2C3__Orightresult__U__X6?lang=eng&suite=cobalt"

res = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for items in soup.find("table",class_="itemTable").find_all("tr"):
    if "New Britain" in items.text:
        data = items.find_all("td")
        name = data[0].a.get_text(strip=True)
        status = data[2].get_text(strip=True)
        print(name,status)
```

Output:

```
New Britain, Jefferson Branch - Children's Department Check Shelf
New Britain, Main Library - Children's Department Check Shelf
New Britain, Main Library - Children's Department Check Shelf
```